# Mapping hash map key/value pairs to named constructor arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to map the key value pairs of a Map to a Scala constructor with named parameters?

That is, given

```scala
class Person(val firstname: String, val lastname: String) {
    ...
}
```

... how can I create an instance of Person using a map like

```scala
val args = Map("firstname" -> "John", "lastname" -> "Doe", "ignored" -> "value")
```

What I am trying to achieve in the end is a nice way of mapping Node4J `Node` objects to Scala value objects.

Comment: I've just found this http://paranamer.codehaus.org , which may come in handy in similar circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key insight here is that the constructor arguments names *are* available, as they are the names of the fields created by the constructor. So **provided that the constructor does nothing with its arguments but assign them to fields**, then we can ignore it and work with the fields directly.

We can use:

```
def setFields[A](o : A, values: Map[String, Any]): A = {
  for ((name, value) <- values) setField(o, name, value)
  o
}

def setField(o: Any, fieldName: String, fieldValue: Any) {
  // TODO - look up the class hierarchy for superclass fields
  o.getClass.getDeclaredFields.find( _.getName == fieldName) match {
    case Some(field) => {
      field.setAccessible(true)
      field.set(o, fieldValue)
    }
    case None =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No field named " + fieldName)
  }
```

Which we can call on a blank person:

```
test("test setFields") {
  val p = setFields(new Person(null, null, -1), Map("firstname" -> "Duncan", "lastname" -> "McGregor", "age" -> 44))
  p.firstname should be ("Duncan")
  p.lastname should be ("McGregor")
  p.age should be (44)
}
```

Of course we can do better with a little pimping:

```
implicit def any2WithFields[A](o: A) = new AnyRef {
  def withFields(values: Map[String, Any]): A = setFields(o, values)
  def withFields(values: Pair[String, Any]*): A = withFields(Map(values :_*))
}
```

so that you can call:

```
new Person(null, null, -1).withFields("firstname" -> "Duncan", "lastname" -> "McGregor", "age" -> 44)
```

---

If having to call the constructor is annoying, Objenesis lets you ignore the lack of a no-arg constructor:

```
val objensis = new ObjenesisStd 

def create[A](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A = 
  objensis.newInstance(m.erasure).asInstanceOf[A]
```

Now we can combine the two to write

```
create[Person].withFields("firstname" -> "Duncan", "lastname" -> "McGregor", "age" -> 44)
```

Comment: This is spot on what I am looking for, especially the final solution using [Objenesis](http://objenesis.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html)  to avoid the call to the default constructor. The only thing that makes me a bit uneasy is relying on the java.lang.reflection API since I am not sure the Scala compiled byte code is 100% compatible with Java's byte code. But if it works... why not? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Christoffer Soop: It isn't "compatible with" Java's byte code, it's exactly the same. It has to be in order to run on JVM.

Comment: @Alexey Yes the byte code is 100% JVM compatible, but you cannot decompile Scala compiled byte code to Java with 100% success rate. How do I know that reflection works? Reflection, to my knowledge, infer Java constructs from byte code but I am not convinced that all scala produced byte code has a Java equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you're looking for a reflection based solution. Have a look at JSON libraries with extractors, which do something similar. For example, [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) has some [examples](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/test/scala/net/liftweb/json/ExtractionExamples.scala),

```
case class Child(name: String, age: Int, birthdate: Option[java.util.Date])

val json = parse("""{ "name": null, "age": 5, "birthdate": null }""")
json.extract[Child] == Child(null, 5, None)
```

To get what you want, you could convert your `Map[String, String]` into JSON format and then run the case class extractor. Or you could look into how the JSON libraries are [implemented using reflection](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/Extraction.scala).

Comment: Yes good tip! However, Duncan's solution is the more complete with an actual working which is why I am selecting his solution as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have domain classes of different arity, so here it is my advice. (all the following is ready for REPL)

Define an extractor class per `TupleN`, e.g. for `Tuple2` (your example):

```
class E2(val t: Tuple2[String, String]) {
  def unapply(m: Map[String,String]): Option[Tuple2[String, String]] =
    for {v1 <- m.get(t._1)
         v2 <- m.get(t._2)}
    yield (v1, v2)
}

// class E3(val t: Tuple2[String,String,String]) ...
```

You may define a helper function to make building extractors easier:

```
def mkMapExtractor(k1: String, k2: String) = new E2( (k1, k2) )
// def mkMapExtractor(k1: String, k2: String, k3: String) = new E3( (k1, k2, k3) )
```

Let's make an extractor object

```
val PersonExt = mkMapExtractor("firstname", "lastname")
```

and build `Person`:

```
val testMap = Map("lastname" -> "L", "firstname" -> "F")
PersonExt.unapply(testMap) map {Person.tupled}
```

or

```
testMap match {
  case PersonExt(f,l) => println(Person(f,l))
  case _ => println("err")
}
```

Adapt to your taste.

P.S. Oops, I didn't realize you asked about named arguments specifically. While my answer is about positional arguments, I shall still leave it here just in case it could be of some help.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the gist of the question was about mapping named parameters, but thanks for the example. I learned at least one new word "arity"... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Map` is essentially just a `List` of tuples you can treat it as such.

```
scala> val person = args.toList match {
   case List(("firstname", firstname), ("lastname", lastname), _) => new Person(firstname, lastname)
   case _ => throw new Exception
}
person: Person = Person(John,Doe)
```

I made `Person` a case class to have the `toString` method generated for me.

Comment: Thanks - elegant but it still forces me to enumerate the named arguments in the case clause. I am thinking more along the lines of Java reflection and the bean API(s) where I could iterate over all the setters, use the property name as the key in the map and invoke the setter.

Comment: I guess the obvious solution is to create a Person object that takes a Map as constructor argument and manually create the setters. Like the elegant and brief syntax of the `val` named parameters though...

Comment: Note that `Map.toList` doesn't guarantee ordering of returned list, so it may well return `List(("ignored", "value"), ("firstname", "John"), ("lastname", "Doe")` instead and the pattern match will fail.

Comment: @Christoffer Soop: You'd need constructor argument names, and they don't seem to be available. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html Scala-specific reflection library may be available in 2.10, but not yet.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov: you are right, but it is also easy to fix with a few alternative cases. Thx for the note anyway.