# Does Scala have object initialization like C#?

Tags: scala, object, initialization

Object initialization in C#:

```
var foo = new Foo() { bar = 5 };
```

which is equivalent of

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = 5;
```

Does Scala have object initialization like C#?

Comment: why don't you just try the exact same code and see what happens??

Comment: @Kim Stebel: the funny thing is that the results would _not_ be equivalent :)

Comment: Who downvoted this question and why?

Comment: it wouldn't be equivalent, but it would achieve the same thing in most cases

Comment: @missingfaktor: downvoted for lack of own research effort

Comment: @Kim Stebel, (a) I always wonder how it is possible you see what I do at my own home, (b) read Huynhjl answer and try to find anything close to this explanation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7455681/97777 for a way to simulate this in some circumstances.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
scala> class Foo { var bar: Int = _ }
defined class Foo

scala> var foo = new Foo() { bar = 5 }
foo: Foo = $anon$1@1ed00d1

scala> var realFoo = new Foo()
realFoo: Foo = Foo@1bedb0
```

You can see that the syntax works (in this case), but also that foo does not have type Foo. It's actually a new subtype of Foo which subclasses it with whatever is between the braces. In this case just the constructor with an additional assignment.

In the general case, the exact C# syntax will not work:

```
scala> class Foo { var bar: Int = _; var baz: String = _ }
defined class Foo

scala> var foo: Foo = new Foo { bar = 5, baz = "bam" }
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ',' found.
       var foo: Foo = new Foo { bar = 5, baz = "bam" }
```

Instead you'll need to type:

```
scala> var foo: Foo = new Foo { bar = 5; baz = "bam" }
foo: Foo = $anon$1@1be20c
```

Foo constructor will run first, then the anonymous type constructor will run next.

I think this is what Kim and Alexey comments refer to.

I don't use C#, but it seems in C# this bit of syntax can only be used to initialize fields, while in Scala it was decided to use this syntax to extend the class like in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer but also lengthy and interesting explanation! Good reading.

Comment: I ran into a bit of a scary situation using Scala. I was trying to use the Java like syntax as an object initialiser from C#. However the class I was anonymously subclassing contained a field that shadowed, without my knowing, a variable that was in scope where I was writing the subclass.

Answer (score 6):

Scala does not have object initialization like C#, but Scala does not need it most of the time. There are **factory methods** for collections, which can easily substitute object initialization of C#'s collections. There are **case classes** with **copy methods**, which help with the initialization of the rest of the objects. There are **anonymous classes**, which help extending a class and initializing an instance of a class with all it's members at the same time.