# What is the most concise way to construct/build JavaBean objects in Scala?

Tags: java, oop, scala, builder, setter

Let's say `Product` is in a Java library that I can't tweak, so to instantiate it by calling setters:

```
val product = new Product
product.setName("Cute Umbrella")
product.setSku("SXO-2")
product.setQuantity(5)
```

I'd prefer to be able to do *something like* this:

```
val product = new Product {
  _.setName("Cute Umbrella")
  _.setSku("SXO-2")
  _.setQuantity(5)
}
```

or better yet:

```
val product =
  new Product(name -> "Cute Umbrella", sku -> "SXO-2", quantity -> 5)
```

Is something like this possible with Scala ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7455681/97777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write an implicit conversion to use Apache Commons BeanUtils

```
  import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils


  implicit def any2WithProperties[T](o: T) = new AnyRef {
    def withProperties(props: Pair[String, Any]*) = {
      for ((key, value) <- props) { BeanUtils.setProperty(o, key, value) }
      o
    }
  }

  test("withProperties") {
    val l = new JLabel().withProperties("background" -> Color.RED, "text" -> "banana")
    l.getBackground should be (Color.RED)
    l.getText should be ("banana")
  }
```

You don't get property name or type checking at compile time, but it is very close to the syntax that you wanted, and is generally very useful in creating eg testdata.

---

Or taking a cue from @retronym's function approach

```
  implicit def any2WithInitialisation[T](o: T) = new AnyRef {
    def withInitialisation(fs: (T =>Unit)*) = { 
      fs.foreach(_(o))
      o
    }
  }

  test("withInitialisation") {
    val l = new JLabel().withInitialisation(
      _.setBackground(Color.RED), 
      _.setText("banana")
    )
    l.getBackground should be (Color.RED)
    l.getText should be ("banana")
  }
```

Comment: (rant) "You don't get any property name or type checking at compile time" - this is what really bugs me about the java beans mentality. We have this statically-typed language that can catch a lot of dumb errors for you, but wth, let's bend over backwards in order to *thwart that language's built-in safety*. Also, let's just use Strings for basically everything. ಠ_ಠ (/rant)

Comment: :-) But hey, there are a few languages that have managed to carve out a niche with only run-time checks. Personally my Java and Scala test code is full of little hacks like these because I know that the tests will fail if they arent correct, and a value the expressiveness.

Comment: While I think losing the type checking is bad, in my specific case it seems an unavoidable tradeoff to get what I want. And your code needs to be written only once and it will work for any class. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the second of these approaches is type safe.

Answer (score 6):

You can import the setters so you don't need to qualify the calls:

```
val product = {
  val p = new Product
  import p._

  setName("Cute Umbrella")
  setSku("SXO-2")
  setQuantity(5)

  p
}
```

If `Product` isn't final, you could also anonymously subclass it and call the setters in the constructor:

```
val product = new Product {
  setName("Cute Umbrella")
  setSku("SXO-2")
  setQuantity(5)
}
```

As soon as you try to instantiate with a Map of property names and values, you lose static type checking, as you resort to reflection. Libraries like Apache Commons BeanUtils can help out, if you still want to go down that path.

Yet another approach is to pass a sequence of anonymous functions to call each setter, and write a utility method to apply them to the object

```
def initializing[A](a: A)(fs: (A => Unit)*) = { fs.foreach(_(a)); a }

initializing(new Product)(
  _.setName("Cute Umbrella"),
  _.setSku("SXO-2"),
  _.setQuantity(5)
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create a Product object as a factory, and call that in your scala. Something like this:

```
object Product {
  def apply(name: String, sku: String, quantity: Int) = {
     val newProd = new Product()
     import newProd._
     setName(name)
     setSku(sku)
     setQuantity(quantity)
     newProd
}
```

and then you can use it exactly as you wanted to (without the new).

```
   val product = Product(name = "Cute Umbrella", sku = "SXO-2", quantity = 5)
```

(apologies if the above doesn't compile. Don't have access to Scala at work :(

Comment: I think you need `=` rather than `->`, but it's a good solution

Comment: @Luigi That's what I get for copying the OP's code ;) Thanks for the correction, and I've edited my response.

Comment: Which means I have to create a factory each class... There could potentially be tens or hundreds of classes... (it still saves redundancy, but was hoping there's a "better" i.e. Scala magic way)

Comment: @Hendy: Correct. I didn't realize you were looking for such a general solution. Personally, I'd go with retronym's solution over the one you've chosen. Both cases are clear what's happening, no extra typing/class creation, and the compiler will tell you if you got a type wrong, or a property no longer exists...

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness if you ever need to go the other way around, reading properties in a javabean style from scala classes, you can use `@BeanProperty` and `@BooleanBeanProperty` annotations:

```
class MyClass(@BeanProperty foo : String, @BooleanBeanProperty bar : Boolean);
```

And then from java:

```
MyClass clazz = new MyClass("foo", true);

assert(clazz.getFoo().equals("foo"));
assert(clazz.isBar());
```