# Copying a case class and changing a list of fields

Tags: scala

Is there a way to copy a case class in scala using a map of fields and their new values?

I tried a way that included reflection so I would like to avoid that

```
def copyWithMap(fieldNameValue: Map[String, Option[AnyREF]]): T
```

when applied to a case class this should make a copy and update the fields that need updating. (specified in the map)

Comment: Similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455681/mapping-hash-map-key-value-pairs-to-named-constructor-arguments-in-scala
Maybe you find some useful hints there.

Comment: Not really, this person knows in advance what the names of the fields are whereas I'm trying to make something more general

Comment: Are you willing to bring in outside libraries? Shapeless has `LabelledGeneric`'s, which solve this problem for you at least when the class is discernible at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for any generic object then you need some way of mapping the compile-time name of a field to the run-time location of that field in the object. The only built-in mechanism for this is reflection, so you can't do what you want without using reflection (or implementing your own generic reflection mechanism, which seems pointless).

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you have to update before you start, you can do something like this:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int, eyeColour: String)
defined class Person

scala> val p1 = Person("Bill", 24, "blue")
p1: Person = Person(Bill,24,blue)

scala> val p2 = p1.copy(name = "Ben", eyeColour = "brown")
p2: Person = Person(Ben,24,brown)
```

If you want to make it more generic, maybe something like this would work (setField taken from [Duncan McGregor's answer in the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458175/8230810) and put in implicit class):

```
implicit class Modify[T](i: T) {
  def modify(m: Map[String, Any]): T = {
    for ((name, value) <- m) setField(name, value)
    i
  }

  def setField(fieldName: String, fieldValue: Any) = {
    i.getClass.getDeclaredFields.find(_.getName == fieldName) match {
      case Some(field) =>
        field.setAccessible(true)
        field.set(i, fieldValue)
      case None =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"No field named $fieldName")
    }
  }
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, eyeColour: String)

val p1 = Person("Bill", 24, "blue")

val p2 = p1.copy().modify(Map("name" -> "Ben", "eyeColour" -> "brown"))
// p2: Person = Person(Ben,24,brown)

p1
// res0: Person = Person(Bill,24,blue)
```

Comment: This updates the class in-place, rather than taking a copy.

Comment: you want `p1.copy.modify(...)`

Comment: @Tim and Dima - good point, I'll modify my answer. Hadn't checked that.

Comment: Thank you, @Dima :)

Comment: The `modify` function can still mutate any object, even immutable ones, so it would be better to copy the object inside the `modify` method to keep it functional.

Comment: @Tim I did try that too but had issues putting it inside `modify` due to the generic type `T`. If you want to have a play around though, feel free to edit my answer if you work out a way to do it. :)